# Should I use an intercept even if my regression model's r-squared value reduces by a lot?

Tags: python, linear-regression, model-evaluations, r-squared

I'm using Python to create a good linear regression model and am having trouble getting good results for my r-squared value.

A quick rundown of what the data is:

– Sales: This dependent variable indicates the total amount spent on each order.

– AgeInMonths: The age in months of the customer. (starts at 300)

– ProfileInMonths: The time in months since the user created the profile.

– NumPrevOrders: The number of previous orders of the customer.

– AvgSpend: The average amount of all previous orders placed by the customer.

– POSR: An internal score (Point-of-Sales Ratio) collected by the shop, which indicates the customer’s likeliness to respond to advertising.

– OPR: An internal score (Order-Purchase Ratio) collected by the shop. It represents the ratio of the number of times a customer makes a purchase to the number of times the customer adds items to a cart.

– Online: The time in minutes spent on the website by the customer before making a purchase.

– Discount: The discount offered on the cart of goods purchased by the customer in the order. This value is given as a percentage, i.e., between 0 and 100.

I'm using :

```
num_reg = smf.ols('Sales ~ AgeInMonths + ProfileInMonths + NumPrevOrders + AvgSpend + POSR + OPR + Online + Discount', data=df).fit()
```

This adds an intercept automatically and I get an R-squared value of 0.185. Without the intercept, I get a R-squared of 0.911.

I've found this on the internet:
"If and only if you are confident that the output should be zero if all of the input variables are 0, only then can you get rid of using an intercept. Ideally, it's preferable to always and always use an intercept in the regression models."

If all variables are 0, then AgeInMonths would also be zero. I assumed the Sales would be 0 if they were 0 years old.

Would this assumption be correct? Should I use a different way of modelling my data? AAny help would be appreciated.